# antlr4 runtime : error while loading shared libraries libantlr4-runtime.so.4.7.1

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, runtime, antlr4

Hey I'm trying to run a transpiler (compiler / translator), that translates alfa to solidity smart contracts.

To run this project, I've followed the following steps:

1. Cloning the runtime [repo](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Cpp) and building the antlr4 runtime using the make command.
2. Pointing the to pre-built runtime (step 1) in the ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake file that's located in the transpiler project.
3. Creating a build file in the transpiler project and running the make command to generate executable "AlfaToSol" in order to convert alfa to solidity

[build folder with all final generated file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seybb.jpg)

ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake file :

```
set(ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar)

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.12.2)
PROJECT(antlr4cpp_fetcher CXX)
INCLUDE(ExternalProject)
FIND_PACKAGE(Git REQUIRED)

FIND_PACKAGE(Java COMPONENTS Runtime REQUIRED)

set(ANTLR4CPP_EXTERNAL_ROOT home/ubuntu/Desktop/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/antlr4cpp)

if(NOT EXISTS "${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find antlr tool. ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION:${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
endif()

if (NOT ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR)
  set(ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/antlr4cpp_generated_src)
endif()


ExternalProject_ADD(
  antlr4cpp
  PREFIX            
  SOURCE_DIR        /home/ubuntu/Desktop/antlr4/runtime/Cpp/
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(antlr4cpp SOURCE_DIR)


list(APPEND ANTLR4CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS ${INSTALL_DIR}/include/antlr4-runtime)
foreach(src_path misc atn dfa tree support)
  list(APPEND ANTLR4CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS ${INSTALL_DIR}/include/antlr4-runtime/${src_path})
endforeach(src_path)

set(ANTLR4CPP_LIBS "${INSTALL_DIR}/lib")



macro(antlr4cpp_process_grammar
    antlr4cpp_project
    antlr4cpp_project_namespace
    antlr4cpp_grammar_lexer
    antlr4cpp_grammar_parser)

  if(EXISTS "${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
    message(STATUS "Found antlr tool: ${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find antlr tool. ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION:${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}")
  endif()

  add_custom_target("antlr4cpp_generation_${antlr4cpp_project_namespace}"
    COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}
    COMMAND
    "${Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE}" -jar "${ANTLR4CPP_JAR_LOCATION}" -Werror -Dlanguage=Cpp -listener -visitor -o "${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}/${antlr4cpp_project_namespace}" -package ${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} "${antlr4cpp_grammar_lexer}" "${antlr4cpp_grammar_parser}"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    DEPENDS "${antlr4cpp_grammar_lexer}" "${antlr4cpp_grammar_parser}"
    )


  FILE(GLOB generated_files ${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}/${antlr4cpp_project_namespace}/*.cpp)


  foreach(generated_file ${generated_files})
    list(APPEND antlr4cpp_src_files_${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} ${generated_file})
    if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
    set_source_files_properties(
      ${generated_file}
      PROPERTIES
      COMPILE_FLAGS -Wno-overloaded-virtual
      )
    endif ()
  endforeach(generated_file)
  message(STATUS "Antlr4Cpp  ${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} Generated: ${generated_files}")

  # export generated include directory
  set(antlr4cpp_include_dirs_${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} ${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}/${antlr4cpp_project_namespace})
  message(STATUS "Antlr4Cpp ${antlr4cpp_project_namespace} include: ${ANTLR4CPP_GENERATED_SRC_DIR}/${antlr4cpp_project_namespace}")

endmacro()
```

**But after running , which is supposed to generate solidity code in the output.sol file: **
`./AlfaToSol input.alfa output.sol`

**I get the following error**

```
./AlfaToSol : error while loading shared libraries: libantlr4-runtime.so.4.7.1
cannot open shared object file : No such file or directory
```

I've tried adding the library libantlr4-runtime.so.4.7.1 in the ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake file, using the target_link_libraries and add_libraries but no luck.

I've been struggling with this problem for the past two days, any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is not relevant to makefiles since you're using cmake.  To understand this you need to understand the difference between _link-time_ library search and _run-time_ library search.  Shared libraries need to be available at both link time **and** runtime, but they don't need to be in the same place at runtime that they were at link time, and the way search is done is different.  The very simplest solution for you is to export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable set to the directory containing the antlr `.so` file: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<dir> ./AlfaToSol input.alfa output.sol`

Comment: @MadScientist Aaah i see, thank you very much for the info, it finally worked !!

Comment: If you want to allow the program to run without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` you will need to venture into understanding the rpath (runtime linker path) and how to configure it in your program, so it knows where to look without having `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set.  That's a more complex topic.  There is documentation in cmake on how to set up RPATH: they try to simplify it but there's only so much that can be done.